# mix a citation and text using natbib

Tags: bibliographies, natbib

I have this .tex file:

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{CostantiniMoller2008,
  title={Carotenoids are minor antioxidants for birds},
  author={Costantini, D and M{\o}ller, AP},
  journal={Functional Ecology},
  volume={22},
  number={2},
  pages={367--370},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}


\usepackage[comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}


\begin{document}
\title{}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\section{Header}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum \citep{CostantiniMoller2008, pers.obs.}


\bibliographystyle{agsm}

\bibliography{refs}


\end{document}
```

I need to cite CostantiniMoller2008 and pers.obs within the same citation. When I try to parse the file as it stands, pers.obs just appears as a ?. How can I cite both CostantiniMoller2008 and pers.obs?

Comment: Does `\citep[][, pers.obs.]{CostantiniMoller2008}` achieve what you want?

Comment: @Ubiquitous - Do you need `, ` at the start of the string `, pers.obs.`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you choose depends in part on whether or not you want a comma to be placed between the author(s) and the year. To generate a citation callout *without* that comma, use a combination of `\citetext` and `\citealt`. For a citation callout *with* the comma, use either `\citep` with a single optional argument, or use a combination of `\citetext` and `\citealp`.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{refs.bib}
@article{CostantiniMoller2008,
  title={Carotenoids are minor antioxidants for birds},
  author={Costantini, D. and M{\o}ller, A. P.},
  journal={Functional Ecology},
  volume={22},
  number={2},
  pages={367--370},
  year={2008},
  publisher={Wiley Online Library}
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}

\usepackage[comma, sort&compress]{natbib} 
\setlength{\bibsep}{0pt plus 0.3ex}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat} % choose the appropriate bib style here
\setlength\parindent{0pt} % just for this example
\begin{document}
\citetext{\citealt[pers.~obs.]{CostantiniMoller2008}} 

\citep[pers.~obs.]{CostantiniMoller2008}

or also:

\citetext{\citealp[pers.~obs.]{CostantiniMoller2008}} 

\bibliography{refs}
\end{document}
```